# Return first date equal to or older than given date?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get a single value from a `pd.DataFrame` by using the following lines:

```
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-03-01', '%Y-%m-%d')

timeranges = [(end - datetime.timedelta(30)),
              (end - datetime.timedelta(60)),
              (end - datetime.timedelta(365))]

nav_df = data[(data['Symbol'] == 'account') & (data['Type'] == 'nav')
               & (data['Date'] >= date)]
```

How do I tell pandas to limit the returning value to the first date that evaluates to `True` in `data['Date'] >= date` ?

**Sample Data:**

http://pastebin.com/1pRatDts

Comment: Can you add sample of data and maybe `date` is `end`?

Comment: You mean if I set it to `data['Date'] == date`? Returns empty, unfortunately; I've added sample data.

Comment: It makes sense, since I only have weekday in my data; I just figured pandas would automatically return the next best thing.

Comment: What does timerages and end do? What is `date` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking off from @jezrael base,

You could use `(data['Date'] >= end).diff().fillna(True)` *to limit the returning values to the first date that evaluates to True in*.

```
In [215]: data[(data['Symbol'] == 'account') &
   .....:      (data['Type'] == 'nav') &
   .....:      (data['Date'] >= end).diff().fillna(True)]
Out[215]:
       Symbol       Date Type       Values
1083  account 2016-03-01  nav  501594.4239
```

Comment: Very interesting solution, but doesnt work, if comparing `Date`  in first row, because `diff` return `NaN`. Try it: `end = '2012-01-01'`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use `Datetime` as string `end` like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('http://pastebin.com/raw/1pRatDts', 
                   sep="\t", 
                   header=None,
                   parse_dates = [1], 
                   names=['Symbol','Date','Type','Values'])
print data.head()
    Symbol       Date Type       Values
0  account 2012-01-02  nav  460515.3849
1  account 2012-01-03  nav  459722.4779
2  account 2012-01-04  nav  460089.9382
3  account 2012-01-05  nav  460961.5919
4  account 2012-01-06  nav  461316.4826


end = '2016-03-01'
nav_df = data[(data['Symbol'] == 'account') & 
              (data['Type'] == 'nav') & 
              (data['Date'] >= end)]
print nav_df
       Symbol       Date Type       Values
1083  account 2016-03-01  nav  501594.4239
1084  account 2016-03-02  nav  500964.1165
1085  account 2016-03-03  nav  500921.3288
1086  account 2016-03-04  nav  500000.0000
```

And first row thanks [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843144/return-first-date-equal-to-or-older-than-given-date/35843423#comment59352285_35843423):

```
print nav_df.head(1)
       Symbol       Date Type       Values
1083  account 2016-03-01  nav  501594.4239
```

Or if you have `Datetimeindex` use [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.first.html):

```
nav_df = nav_df.set_index('Date')

print nav_df.first('D')
             Symbol Type       Values
Date                                 
2016-03-01  account  nav  501594.4239
```

Comment: `... .head(1)` or `... .iloc[0]` would give you the first value.